# tkinter strange glitches on Mac M1 chipset

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to develop a simple GUI interface using TKinter; however, I noticed that most of the guides and tool demos are not working correctly on the Mac M1 chipset.

In particular, I want to develop this GUI:
[image: GUI]

I write the following code (the implementation is without the terminal output):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def select_input_dir():
 input_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
 input_entry.delete(0, END)
 input_entry.insert(0, input_dir)

def select_output_dir():
 output_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
 output_entry.delete(0, END)
 output_entry.insert(0, output_dir)

def run():
 input_dir = input_entry.get()
 output_dir = output_entry.get()
 parallel = parallel_checkbox.get()
 num_walks = int(num_walks_entry.get())
 print("Input Directory:", input_dir)
 print("Output Directory:", output_dir)
 print("Parallel:", parallel)
 print("Number of Walks:", num_walks)

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI Example")
root.configure(bg="white")
input_label = Label(root, text="Input", bg="white")
input_label.pack()
input_entry = Entry(root)
input_entry.pack()
input_button = Button(root, text="Select Input Dir", command=select_input_dir)
input_button.pack()
output_label = Label(root, text="Output", bg="white")
output_label.pack()
output_entry = Entry(root)
output_entry.pack()
output_button = Button(root, text="Select Output Dir", command=select_output_dir)
output_button.pack()
parallel_checkbox = IntVar()
parallel_checkbox.set(0)
parallel_checkbutton = Checkbutton(root, text="Parallel", variable=parallel_checkbox,    bg="white")
parallel_checkbutton.pack()
num_walks_label = Label(root, text="Select Number of Walks", bg="white")
num_walks_label.pack()
num_walks_entry = Entry(root)
num_walks_entry.pack()
run_button = Button(root, text="Run", command=run, bg="light gray")
run_button.pack()
exit_button = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.quit, bg="light gray")
exit_button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

However, this snippet of code produce
[image: GUI results]

In addition, I noticed that there are stranger glitches when I move the mouse (in particular, the colors of the buttons change), and I cannot change the background color of the window (I tried with several different commands but without success)

I tried several guides but was unsuccessful. In particular, I read that the library TKinter does not correctly work with the Mac M1 chipset, but I did not find a good alternative.

How can I do that?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Is it an official python.org binary?  For what it's worth, your program seems to work fine with Python 3.9 on FreeBSD UNIX.

Comment: Are you asking about the colors, or the widget layout? The layout and the text on the widgets in the code you posted is very different from your screenshot, and the layout appears like I would expect it to.

Comment: This is most likely because you are using the system version of python. Apple's version is buggy. I recommend you install python and tkinter from python.org.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is with the `foreground` or `fg` element. It controls the text color `Label`s and the text box color for `Entry`s. Adding it like `input_label = Label(root, text="Input", fg="black", bg="white")` allows them to show up.

Secondly, using a `.grid(column=X, row=Y)` instead of `.pack()` allows tkinter to do 2 columns nicely. [This can help you out.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-grid-method-in-tkinter/)

Finally, you can `.grid(column=1, row=1)` and `.pack()` on the same line as long as you do not need to keep the object (for things like the labels).

All in all it would look something like this:

```py
root = Tk()
root.title("GUI Example")
root.configure(background="white")
Label(root, text="Input", foreground="black", background="white").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=40)
input_entry = Entry(root, bg="white", fg="black")
input_entry.grid(row=1, column=2) # Can't .grid() on the same line because we need the entry object later.
...
```

On my M1 mac, these changes work as long as I resize the window after running the code. It appears to need a bit of a "refresh" so to speak.